# for-each loop NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i keep getting nullpointerexception no matter what i tried. can provide more code if required.

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear){
    ArrayList<Lamborghini> selectedCars = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for(Lamborghini c : inventory){
        if(c == null){
            continue;
        }
        if(c.getModelYear()>= startYear && c.getModelYear()<= endYear){
            selectedCars.add(c);
        }
    }
    return selectedCars.size();
}
```

Comment: In which line you get the NPE?

Comment: Where from you get inventory in the loop

Comment: why do you overload your logic with adding the cars into the array list if you just return the size of this list? why not using a counter?

Comment: Most likely your "inventory" object is null.

Comment: Could you please put the stack trace, so tht we can see where the NPE is coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i couldn't reply to any of you, and I realized the code I left was not compete, but i finally figured out what was wrong, it doesn't make sense to me but it did fix the problem, and the problem wasn't even in the method i posted.

originally I had (ArrayList Lamborghini) when i was initializing the inventory arraylist:

```
public class LamborghiniCarLot
{
private String lotName;
private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;

public LamborghiniCarLot()
{
 ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
}

public LamborghiniCarLot(String lotName){
  ArrayList<Lamborghini>inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
    setLotName(lotName);
```

then I tried to remove the (ArrayList Lamborghini) before inventory and it fixed everything:

```
public LamborghiniCarLot()
{
    inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
}

public LamborghiniCarLot(String lotName){
    inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();
    setLotName(lotName);
```

It would be appreciated if someone can explain to me what that changed and why it wouldn't work with arraylist lamborghini before inventory. I am new to programming so please be detailed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `inventory` is null.

Comment: If `inventory` is empty list, i dont think there will be an NPE. It should be null.

Answer (score 0):

if `getModelYear` returns null then you will get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

2 Posibilities:--

1. Mostly your inventory object reference is null
2. your if code--

   if (c.getModelYear()>= startYear && c.getModelYear()<= endYear)

Try below if instead above --

```
if(((c.getModelYear()!=null)?c.getModelYear():0)>=startYear&&
        c.getModelYear()<= endYear)
```

I am Assusming you have some proper value in 'startYear' and 'endYear' apart from Zero.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use java 8 the following code should work:

```
if(inventory==null){
        return 0;
}
return inventory.stream().filter((Lamborghini c)-> c!=null && c.getModelYear()>= startYear && c.getModelYear()<= endYear).count();
```

but without you telling us WHERE exactly the nullpointer is happening, it's just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

You don't two ifs. because "for" loop will only continue for each c value.

```
public int howManyBetweenTheseYears(int startYear, int endYear)
{
    ArrayList<Lamborghini> selectedCars = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for(Lamborghini c : inventory)
    {       
        if(c.getModelYear()>= startYear && c.getModelYear()<= endYear)
        {
            selectedCars.add(c);
        }
    }
    return selectedCars.size();
 }
```

Also have a variable that holds the return value and initiate it by giving size 0. else it will give you nullpointerexception if can't find any matching car.